# Syncing Joomla between Dev and Prod servers?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, synchronization, production

I'm curious how other people have approached this. Our group has been given the directive of implementing an internal website utilizing Joomla. We've set up a dev server for the person who is responsible for maintaining the site, and a production server. We're using IIS and the current version of Joomla.

I can sync the two with Akeeba Backup Core and Kickstart, but it seems an "All-or-Nothing" choice. It works, but if she's doing work on, for example, the look and feel of the site, but just wants to sync content, that doesn't appear to be doable.

I feel that someone out there must have tackled this goal before, but web searches seem to turn up people running dev/prod on the same server but in different subdirectories, or ignore the "all-or-nothing"ness of the issue, going for the "Do all at once" approach, which doesn't seem practical. Content changes frequently, but not-so the look/feel.

Answer (score 2):

We've been doing this for several years now. We use a dev server and a prod server. When we make content changes on dev, we use phpMyAdmin to copy the content table from the dev db to the prod db. In some respects, it's still an all-or-nothing approach, because we have to copy the entire content table at once. This means you can't have some pages still in development when you do the copy. In other respects, it still a piecemeal approach, because we can copy individual tables such as modules, menus, etc. But again, it's ALL modules at once, ALL menus at once, etc. There is a way in phpMyAdmin to copy an individual page or item from a table in dev and put it in the corresponding table in prod, but it's a little cumbersome. It works, though.

As for design elements (images, css, template changes, etc.) we do the same thing, but the copying is done manually by ftp from one server to the other. Obviously this is the same method for things like pdf files on dev that need moved to prod.

In summary, this method has worked fairly well for us for a long time. But it's limitation is that you must realize you're copying an entire table at once.

The positive of all of this is that when we have pages that are in development, I have leverage over the content people to hurry and finish their work because one unfinished page can hold up the entire site!

Answer (score 0):

This workflow dilemma has come up a few times for me.

You mention changes to look and feel, and that is simpler really, if it is just template changes.  It is quite simpler to pull down an Akeeba Backup of the live server, kickstart it onto a local server, work on the template files, and then upload the updated template files to the live server.

That said, if it is more than CSS and HTML tweaks to existing files, it can be a more involved process.

Personally I've not found a silver bullet for this sort of thing, but with some forethought and planning it is not too bad.